# Java 8 Check if a string follows a b n pattern

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to do coding practise

Given a string str, return true string follows pattern anbn, i.e., it has a’s followed by b’s such that the number of a’s and b’s are same.

Input : str = "aabb"
Output : Yes

Input : str = "abab"
Output : No

Input : str = "aabbb"
Output : No

I have done with following code

```
public static boolean isAnBn(String s) 
{ 
    int l = s.length(); 

    // Only even length strings will have same number of a's and b's 
    if (l%2 == 1) 
    { 
        return false; 
    } 
    // Set two pointers, one from the left and another from right 
    int i = 0; 
    int j = l-1; 

    // Compare the characters till the center 
    while (i<j) 
    { 
        if(s.charAt(i) != 'a' || s.charAt(j) != 'b') 
        { 
            return false; 
        } 
        i++; 
        j--; 
    } 
    return true;     
}
```

is there is another way we can refactor the code using Java 8

any help will be appreciated

Comment: _"is there is another way we can refactor the code using Java 8"_ - plenty. But why would you want to do that? What is your goal?

Comment: I am new to java 8 some coding challenge require to do it in java 8

Comment: Your code _is_ in Java 8.  No, it's not using streams or any of the other neat features that came in with Java 8, but it's still perfectly good Java 8.

Comment: Take “anbn” literally: `if(s.length()%2 == 1) return false; int n = s.length() / 2; return s.matches("a{"+n+"}b{"+n+'}');`

Comment: I'm assuming that the point of this exercise is to tie into some theoretical CS concepts, more specifically automata theory and formal language theory. Although there are more practical solutions already provided, a CS 101 approach would be to write a pushdown automata. For each character, if you encounter 'a', push it onto the stack. If you encounter 'b', pop from the stack. At the end of the string, if your stack is empty, you accept.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isAnBn(String s) 
    { 

        Map<Character, Integer> freqs = new HashMap<>();
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            freqs.merge(c,                  // key = char
                        1,                  // value to merge
                        Integer::sum);      // counting
        }
        if(freqs.get('a') == freqs.get('b') )
            return true;
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: You are comparing boxed `Integer` with == which [will fail if the values are outside of the range of the integer cache](https://ideone.com/OI6N55).

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions is the simplest and most readable solution.

Is the string's length even? And is the first half all As? And is the second half all Bs?

```
final int midPoint = s.length() / 2;
return (s.length() % 2 == 0)
    && s.substring(0, midPoint).matches("a+")
    && s.substring(midPoint).matches("b+");
```

`+` means 1 or more times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
public static boolean isAnBn(final String str){

    //cannot be on pattern if not an even length of str 
    if (str == null || str.length() % 2 != 0){
        return false;
    }

    final String aHalf = str.substring(0,str.length()/2);
    final Boolean isAs = isMatch(aHalf, "^[a]+$");

    final String bHalf = str.substring(str.length()/2);
    final Boolean isBs = isMatch(bHalf, "^[b]+$");

    return isAs && isBs;
}

private static Boolean isMatch(final String string, final String regex) {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    return pattern.matcher(string).matches();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex is the easiest way:

```
public static boolean isAnBn(String s) 
{ 
    int aCount = (int) s.chars().filter(ch -> ch =='a').count();//Line 1
    return Pattern.matches("a{"+aCount+"}b{"+aCount+"}", s);// Line 2
}
```

Explanation :

Line 1 will find number of occurrence of `a` in the string using Java 8 stream API.

Line 2 will use regex to check the pattern.

Comment: More concise to write `return s.matches(expr);` than your way. `String::matches` delegates to `Pattern::matches` so the result is identical